# Regex to get string before `:` till multiple white spaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

We are trying to make an object from a string coming up, which is not following any proper pattern.

`HP: (000)123-4567   AGE: 53      S:F^   0001 S. Potomac                     DOB: 11/04/1900  LOC: E.ER      ^   Aurora,CO  80088                    PHYS: ISADE - jhghj,Devon Chase  ^   PHONE #: 000-000-0000               EXAM DATE: 12/24/2017 STATUS: REG ER^     FAX #: 000-000-0000               A#: Eu67765765hh      U#: E49857684957^ ^ PAGE  1`

In order to get the properties I am trying to fetch from colon backwards till multiple white spaces.

this is what i came up with.

`^(.*?)(?<=\:).*?(?=\:)`

This reads from `:` to `:` i.e `HP: (000)123-4567   AGE` as output

But I need to separate all heading with their data.

```
HP: (000)123-4567
AGE: 53
S: F^ 0001 S. Potomac
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can the values contain white spaces and a colon themself as well? Are the attribute names always in capital letters?

Comment: Yes, All the attributes name will be in capital letters. And also they may be one point or more then one.

Comment: Why did you say that you need to collect `E.ER      ^   Aurora,CO  80088`, yet in your own code have shown that `S` value should be just `F`, not `F^   0001 S. Potomac`?

Comment: Is `FAX #:` an attribute with the name `FAX` or is the hash part of the key?

Comment: @raina77ow yes my bad the value for S should be `F^   0001 S. Potomac                    `

Comment: @FaheemAlam Any feedback on the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex seems to work on the given sample ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/0nF3BR/2)):

```
([^:]+):(.+?)(?=(?:[A-Z#]+ ?)+:|$)
```

It uses combination of lazy quantifier and lookahead expression to separate attributes and their values.

Comment: Its doesn't work. As we need to neglect the `^`. as for 
LOC the value should be `E.ER      ^   Aurora,CO  80088`

Comment: Updated my answer, now it uses `(?:[A-Z#]+ ?)+:` lookahead as pattern for a given attribute. With that said, you might miss values which can be treated as both.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

```
((?:[A-Z]+\s*)*#?):\s*([\s\S]*?(?=$|\s+(?:[A-Z]+\s*)*#?:))
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c0HP3w/6)

**Explanation:**

- `((?:[A-Z]+\s*)*#?)` - Group 1 containing 0+ occurrences of (1+ occurrences of a capital Letter followed by 0+ white-spaces) followed by an optional `#`
- `:\s*` - matches a `:` followed 0+ occurrences of whitespaces
- `([\s\S]*?(?=$|\s+(?:[A-Z]+\s*)*#?:))` - Group 2 containing sequence of characters which are followed by either end-of string OR the next Property name(`\s+(?:[A-Z]+\s*)*#?:`)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
[a-zA-Z]*:([^:]*)\s?
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP8BE0/1)

Comment: It catches the next attribute name as a value for the last attribute

Comment: i would go with @raina77ow 's answer